# LocalDateTime - deserialization with LocalDateTime.parse

Tags: java, json, datetime, jackson, deserialization

I have the field `initiationDate` which serialises by `ToStringSerializer` class to ISO-8601 format.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime initiationDate;
```

When I receive the following JSON,

```
...
"initiationDate": "2016-05-11T17:32:20.897",
...
```

I want to deserialize it by `LocalDateTime.parse(CharSequence text)` factory method. All my attempts ended with `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException`:

> Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class `java.time.LocalDateTime`] from `String` value (`'2016-05-11T17:32:20.897'`); no single-`String` constructor/factory method

How do I achieve that? How can I specify factory method?

---

EDIT:

The problem has been solved by including  [jackson-datatype-jsr310 module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310) to the project and using `@JsonDeserialize` with `LocalDateTimeDeserializer`.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime initiationDate;
```

Comment: I don't know that it uses `parse`, but have you added the appropriate extension, [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, no, how does it solve my problem? I need to specify   the factory method. `LocalDateTime.parse("2016-05-11T17:32:20.897")` works fine.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Vanilla Jackson doesn't have a way to **deserialize** a `LocalDateTime` object from any JSON string value.

You have a few options. You can create and register your own `JsonDeserializer` which will use `LocalDateTime#parse`.

```
class ParseDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {
    public ParseDeserializer() {
        super(LocalDateTime.class);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(p.getValueAsString()); // or overloaded with an appropriate format
    }
}
...
@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = ParseDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime initiationDate;
```

Or you can add [Jackson's `java.time` extension](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310) to your classpath and register the appropriate `Module` with your `ObjectMapper`.

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

and let Jackson do the conversion for you. Internally, this uses `LocalDateTime#parse` with one of the standard formats. Fortunately, it supports values like

```
2016-05-11T17:32:20.897
```

out of the box.

Comment: thank you, the second way is more pretty for me, I used it with `@JsonDeserialize` instead of module registration

Comment: Yeah, I also went the second way: objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());. I voted up.

Answer (score 9):

For those who want to parse custom date-time format.

1) Add dependency

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.8"
```

2) Json annotation with date-time format

```
public class ClientRestObject {

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

}
```

3) Register Java8 module in ObjectMapper

```
private static ObjectMapper buildObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //To parse LocalDateTime
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Comment: @András are you saying that when you do a post request the LocalDateTime is null within your ClientRestObject? I'm having the same issue, and was wondering how you resolved it.

Comment: maybe late to the party but checkout the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327970/deserialize-java-8-localdatetime-with-jacksonmapper

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
//To parse LocalDateTime
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

This works for me, Thanks !