# Deserialize Java 8 LocalDateTime with JacksonMapper

Tags: java, json, jpa, spring-boot, jackson

I have read several questions with answers here in SO concerning serialization and deserialization between `java.time.LocalDateTime` and JSON property but I can't seem to get it working.

I have managed to configure my Spring Boot Application to return the dates in the format I desire (`YYY-MM-dd HH:mm`) but I have problems accepting values in this format in JSON.

These are all the things I have done so far:

Added maven dependency for `jsr310`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Specified `jsr310` in my main class:

```
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { App.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class })
```

Disabled serialization as timestamps in `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

And this is my entity mapping for datetime:

```
@Column(name = "start_date")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm")
private LocalDateTime startDate;
```

In my database, I store this date as TIMESTAMP in the following format: `2016-12-01T23:00:00+00:00`.

If I access this entity via my controller, it returns the JSON with correct startDate format. When I try to post it and deserialize it though, using `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm` format, I get the following exception:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2016-10-30T14:22:25.285+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "Could not read document: Can not deserialize value of type java.time.LocalDateTime from String \"2017-01-01 20:00\": Text '2017-01-01 20:00' could not be parsed: 
    Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=1, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2017, DayOfMonth=1},ISO resolved to 20:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@679a734d; line: 6, column: 16] (through reference chain: 
        com.gigsterous.api.model.Event[\"startDate\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: 
        Can not deserialize value of type java.time.LocalDateTime from String \"2017-01-01 20:00\": 
        Text '2017-01-01 20:00' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=1, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2017, DayOfMonth=1},ISO resolved to 20:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed\n 
        at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@679a734d; line: 6, column: 16] (through reference chain: com.gigsterous.api.model.Event[\"startDate\"])",
  "path": "/api/events"
}
```

I know that there are many answers concerning this topic but following them and trying for couple of hours did not help me to figure out what am I doing wrong so I would be glad if someone could point out to me what am I missing. Thanks for any input on this!

EDIT: These are all the classes involved in the process:

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Event, Long> {
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Event> createEvent(@RequestBody Event event) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(eventRepo.save(event), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

My JSON request payalod:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "startDate": "2017-01-01 20:00"
}
```

Event:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Event {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "event_id")
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime startDate;
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the rest of the trace so we all can verify which classes are involved in parsing the value? Also DateTimeFormat annotation looks out of place

Comment: @Ivan I added all the details to my question and updated the trace

Comment: Did you do anything special to get it to output the error message like that? I have a similar issue, except that my localdatetime just comes through as null on a post request, even though I can do a Get and it's formatted fine.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The date time you're passing is not an ISO local date time format.

Change to

```
@Column(name = "start_date")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm")
private LocalDateTime startDate;
```

and pass the date string in the format '2011-12-03T10:15:30'.

But if you still want to pass your custom format, you just have to specify the right formatter.

Change to

```
@Column(name = "start_date")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))
@JsonFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm")
private LocalDateTime startDate;
```

I think your problem is the @DateTimeFormat has no effect at all. As the Jackson is doing the deserialization and it doesn't know anything about spring annotation, and I don't see spring scanning this annotation in the deserialization context.

Alternatively, you can try setting the formatter while registering the Java time module.

```
LocalDateTimeDeserializer localDateTimeDeserializer = new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
module.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, localDateTimeDeserializer);
```

Here is the test case with the deseralizer which works fine. Maybe try to get rid of that DateTimeFormat annotation altogether.

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class JacksonLocalDateTimeTest {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        LocalDateTimeDeserializer localDateTimeDeserializer =  new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
        module.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, localDateTimeDeserializer);
        objectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
                .modules(module)
                .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        final String json = "{ \"date\": \"2016-11-08 12:00\" }";
        final JsonType instance = objectMapper.readValue(json, JsonType.class);

        assertEquals(LocalDateTime.parse("2016-11-08 12:00",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") ), instance.getDate());
    }
}


class JsonType {
    private LocalDateTime date;

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an error with this saying I cannot convert from DateTimeFormatter to DateTimeFormat.ISO

Comment: Use the spring equalivent for that  formatter. you get the idea right ?

Comment: There is no such class called DateTimeFormatter in Spring. There is only DateTimeFormat (I mentioned it in my question) and i tried both formats with it (2011-12-03T10:15:30 and 2011-12-03 10:15). Neither worked

Comment: okay. There has to be a way to pass the  custom pattern to that datetimeformat annotation.

Comment: I sure hope so, that's basically my question. I tried a lot of combinations but nothing worked so far (including @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"))

Comment: I cant test it now. Can you try @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")

Comment: I did, see my comment above?

Comment: No, that does not help

Comment: Updated. Please take a look.

Comment: Added a test case with LocalDateTime Deserailizer. Please take a look.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I made it work and will award bounty once it allows me to

Comment: YYYY is just wrong. Do not overcomplicate your code and change it to yyyy

Comment: DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE throws compile time error : `attribute value must be constant`

Comment: I had the same problem as @Smajil , for some reason DateTimeFormat and JsonFormat were not effective (even though JsonFormat is a Jackson annotation). Many ppl suggested implementing my own custom Deserializer but I didn't want to implement one Deserializer for every Json class that I had. This answer saved my day, short sweet and effective

Comment: As @ankit said this will not compile. `Attribute value must be constant`

Comment: It just not compiles

Comment: This is the wrong information. DateTimeFormatter is a different class than DateTimeFormat. DateTimeFormatter only has a select few enum choices, unlike DateTimeFormatter, which has a wide variety. And, by choosing DateTimeFormat.DATE_TIME, you wind up with millis despite the javadoc, which is why I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: This part is worng: @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)

Answer (score 33):

You used wrong letter case for year in line:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm")
```

Should be:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
```

With this change everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:

```
 @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
 private LocalDateTime startDate;
```

Comment: yup.. was looking for this thing. For that exact date-time value as mentioned in question "2016-10-30T14:22:25.285+0000", this is the solution which worked for me.

Comment: Thanks this fix my parsing from 
2022-02-21T17:57:53.049+0000. But what shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING mean?

Comment: I had to make a slight change to the pattern (use  ` around the Z):
`@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")`

Answer (score 10):

There are **two** problems with your code:

#### 1. Use of wrong type

`LocalDateTime` does not support timezone. Given below is an [overview of java.time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) and you can see that the type which matches with your date-time string, `2016-12-01T23:00:00+00:00` is `OffsetDateTime` because it has a zone offset of `+00:00`.

[image]

Change your declaration as follows:

```
private OffsetDateTime startDate;
```

#### 2. Use of wrong format

There are two problems with the format:

- You need to use `y` (year-of-era ) instead of `Y` (week-based-year).  Check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34691582/10819573) to learn more about it. In fact, I recommend you use `u` (year) instead of `y` (year-of-era ). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) for more details on it.
- You need to use `XXX` or `ZZZZZ` for the offset part i.e. your format should be `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:m:ssXXX`.

Check the [documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) of `DateTimeFormatter` for more details about these symbols/formats.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2019-10-21T13:00:00+02:00";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:m:ssXXX");
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2019-10-21T13:00+02:00
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 9):

UPDATE:

Change to:

```
@Column(name = "start_date")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
private LocalDateTime startDate;
```

JSON request:

```
{
 "startDate":"2019-04-02 11:45"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can implement your JsonSerializer

See:

That your propertie in bean

```
@JsonProperty("start_date")
@JsonFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm")
@JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
private Date startDate;
```

That way implement your custom class

```
public class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> implements ContextualSerializer<Date> {

    private final String format;

    private DateSerializer(final String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    public DateSerializer() {
        this.format = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(final Date value, final JsonGenerator jgen, final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeString(new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(value));
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<Date> createContextual(final SerializationConfig serializationConfig, final BeanProperty beanProperty) throws JsonMappingException {
        final AnnotatedElement annotated = beanProperty.getMember().getAnnotated();
        return new DateSerializer(annotated.getAnnotation(JsonFormat.class).value());
    }

}
```

Try this after post result for us.

Comment: Please answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129200/resolverstyle-strict-is-not-working-in-datetimeformatiso-datetimeformat-iso?noredirect=1#comment91412598_52129200

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me :

```
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.ISO;

@Column(name="end_date", nullable = false)
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
private LocalDateTime endDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me..

```
@Column(name = "lastUpdateTime")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME,pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" )   
@JsonIgnore
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for this JSON `{ "pickupDate":"2014-01-01T00:00:00" }`

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime pickupDate;
```

Comment: or you can define your custom deserializer if required `@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)`