# LocalDate throws jsonmappingexception

Tags: java, resttemplate, localdate

I am trying to set the current date in my domain class with this code

```
private LocalDate createdUTC = LocalDate.now(Clock.systemUTC());
```

I do not have any setter for this property only getter. When I send a request through **RestTemplate** to my controller I get this error

`{
  "responseCode": 500,
  "responseText": "Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDateTime: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6bde8de2; line: 1, column: 352] (through reference OrganizationResponse[\"createdUTC\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDateTime: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6bde8de2; line: 1, column: 352] (through reference chain: OrganizationResponse[\"createdUTC\"])"
}`

What I have tried so far are solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40476708/2741980) and [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5506)

Comment: Have you tried this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952472/serialize-deserialize-java-8-java-time-with-jackson-json-mapper

Comment: I have added this `@EntityScan(
        basePackageClasses = {Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class}
)` in my main class. Still it throws the same error.