# How to solve error Code 45 : serialize/deserialize LocalDate springboot using Json ObjectMapper

Tags: postman, objectmapper, jackson-databind, localdate

Below is the error message I get :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"2018-10-10"; line: 1, column: 6]
```

Below is my **UPDATED** code to read date from post man Json: { "modifiedDate":"2018-09-10"}

```
String modifiedDateJson = data.get("modifiedDate").asText();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(modifiedDateJson);
        String output = dateFormat.format(date);


        Date modifiedDateDf = mapper.readValue(modifiedDateJson,Date.class);
        LocalDate modifiedDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Comment: Does the error occur at the data.get or the mapper.readValue?

Comment: At mapper.readValue

Comment: Have you looked at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327970/deserialize-java-8-localdatetime-with-jacksonmapper/40330249

Comment: You could try [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates) (#11) `SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    mapper.setDateFormat(df);` before `mapper.readValue()`

Comment: Please allow me to rebuild using simple  date format...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got the answerto my problem of error code 45; answer is as simple as ABC;

(  thanks for your time those of you who tried your levels best ... )

And please excuse my answer/code for not being indented; am using a phone to post this answer...and I hope it helps someone.

## First thing .

1. Receive date:

   String modifiedDate = data.get ("modifiedDate").asText ();

## Second thing...

2. Parse local date:

   LocalDate dateToSave = LocalDate.parse(modifiedDate);

   That's it ...

See also for more insights: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-how-to-convert-string-to-localdate/