# Java LocalDate and Json parse

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'am using a localDate to store a date coming from a client like this dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss
I use the Json format to manage this date.
But i have this error:

```
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "06/11/2018 17:01:35": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate
```

here is my class

```
@Entity
```

public class Audit implements Serializable{

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String username;
@JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDate loginDate;
```

Comment: I would like to know the right pattern that i should use

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327970/deserialize-java-8-localdatetime-with-jacksonmapper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize Java 8 LocalDateTime with JacksonMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327970/deserialize-java-8-localdatetime-with-jacksonmapper)