# Joda DateTimeFormatter - The method ofPattern(String) is undefined

Tags: java, time

I am trying to parse dates to `LocalDateTime`.
Input dates -

```
{
    "meetingTitle":"Test",
    "fromTime":"2018-10-30 12:44",
    "toTime":"2018-10-30 12:44"
}
```

And POJO -

```
private String meetingTitle;
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))
@JsonFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm")
private LocalDateTime fromTime;
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))
@JsonFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm")
private LocalDateTime toTime;
```

But I got this compilation error

```
The method ofPattern(String) is undefined for the type DateTimeFormatter
```

Imports -

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
```

Did I missed something from [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327970/deserialize-java-8-localdatetime-with-jacksonmapper/40330249)?

Comment: That example isn't about joda time but the `java.time` classes. So it uses `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` method is part of the `java.time` API, which is better than jodatime (written by the same person, and afterwards, with the lessons learned by jodatime as guidance). Jodatime is at this point obsoleted by the java.time API.

Do you have a particularly good reason for continuing to use it? If not, you should move to `java.time` API instead; it's quite similar so it should not involve much work to do so.

In jodatime, the call is `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")`. See [the javadoc for joda-time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html).