# Spring boot: JSON deserialize date and time with time zone to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, java-time

I'm using Java 11, Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE. How can I deserialize "2019-10-21T13:00:00+02:00" to LocalDateTime?

Tried so far:

```
  @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
  @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
  @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
  private LocalDateTime startTime;
```

But I get the following error:

```
2021-02-19 07:45:41.402  WARN 801117 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "2019-10-21T13:00:00+02:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2019-10-21T13:00:00+02:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "2019-10-21T13:00:00+02:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2019-10-21T13:00:00+02:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: example.app.dto.DtoRequest["startTime"])]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize Java 8 LocalDateTime with JacksonMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327970/deserialize-java-8-localdatetime-with-jacksonmapper)

Comment: The value shown contains a time zone offset, and should be mapped to an `OffsetDateTime`, not a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @RoarS. - The duplicate target that you have mentioned doesn't answer this question. Please check the answer below for details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are **two** problems with your code:

#### 1. Use of wrong type

> Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String
> "2019-10-21T13:00:00+02:00": Failed to deserialize
> java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException)
> Text '2019-10-21T13:00:00+02:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text
> found at index 19

If you analyze the error message, you will find that it is clearly telling you that there is some problem at index 19.

```
2019-10-21T13:00:00+02:00
// index 19 ---->  ^
```

And, the problem is that `LocalDateTime` does not support timezone. Given below is an [overview of java.time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) and you can see that the type which matches with your date-time string is `OffsetDateTime` because it has a zone offset of `+02:00` hours.

[image]

Change your declaration as follows:

```
private OffsetDateTime startTime;
```

#### 2. Use of wrong format

You need to use `XXX` for the offset part i.e. your format should be `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:m:ssXXX`. If you want to stick to `Z`, you need to use `ZZZZZ`. Check the [documentation page of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for more details.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2019-10-21T13:00:00+02:00";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:m:ssXXX");
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2019-10-21T13:00+02:00
```

---

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Also related, **[RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)** - ***Date and Time on the Internet: Timestamps***

> *This document defines a date and time format for use in Internet
>
> protocols that is a profile of the **ISO 8601** standard for
>
> representation of dates and times using the Gregorian calendar.*

Comment: This answer about switching to Zoned/Offset time format saved my day. Thanks