# Deserialize '2021-09-24 00:00:00' date format via Jackson when using lombok @Builder

Tags: java, date, jackson, lombok, pojo

I have the following object from the response

```
{
"upload_date": "2021-09-24 00:00:00"
}
```

I am using jackson to deserialize into LocalDateTime field

```
@Getter
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = AdGroup.AdGroupBuilder.class)
public class AdGroup {

    @JsonProperty("upload_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime uploadDate;

}
```

But I get `'Cannot deserialize value of type java.time.LocalDateTime from String "2021-09-24 00:00:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2021-09-24 00:00:00' could not be parsed at index 10'`
I tried to use "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" pattern, with/without 'shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING' but the same error always.

Comment: Does the accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327970/deserialize-java-8-localdatetime-with-jacksonmapper help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize Java 8 LocalDateTime with JacksonMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327970/deserialize-java-8-localdatetime-with-jacksonmapper)

Comment: I didn't add an important thing that I also use lombok @Builder so that was the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gets fixed by:

```
@Getter
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = AdGroup.AdGroupBuilder.class)
public class AdGroup {
        
   public static class AdGroupBuilder {
   @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
   private LocalDateTime uploadDate;
   }

@JsonProperty("upload_date")
private LocalDateTime uploadDate;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try -

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

And value exmaple - "2021-12-08T16:49:02.449Z"