# Jackson LocalDate/Time deserialization

Tags: java, jersey, jackson2, jersey-test-framework

I configured jackson so that it gives me a smiple string representation if `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.time.LocalDateTime`. This works find in the serialization process, e.g when I get data on the REST api.

It doesn't work the other way round though. When I try to send data to the server and the JSON should be parsed to java objects this exception is thrown:

> javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDateTime: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2018-04-19T14:10:30.903')

After a few hours of research I managed to get it to work, but only with the attributes I annotated with `@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)` or `@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)` respectively.

In my opinion it would be ideal, if I could define these mappings in one central place.

ObjectMapper configuration:

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        return mapper;
    }
}
```

I tried to add custom deserializers to the JavaTimeModule, but without success:

```
JavaTimeModule dateTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
dateTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, LocalDateDeserializer.INSTANCE);
dateTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, LocalDateTimeDeserializer.INSTANCE);

mapper.registerModule(dateTimeModule);
```

Long story short: Is there a way to define the mapping globally, so that I do not need these annotations on every field. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Alright: I tested it with postman and without the annotations and it worked as expected. However, when I run the unit test (JerseyTest) it throws the mentioned exception. I register the `ObjectMapperContextResolver` to the test application, but probably I am missing something.

Sorry about not mentioning that I was in the unit tests.

TestClass:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;


public class PocRestTest extends JerseyTest {

    private static PocService mockedPocService;

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        mockedPocService = Mockito.mock(PocService.class);
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.register(new PocRest(mockedPocService));
        config.register(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);
        return config;
    }

    private Poc dto;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        dto = new Poc();
        dto.setId(1);
        dto.setName("hi rest");
        dto.setDate(LocalDate.now());
        dto.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());

        doReturn(dto).when(mockedPocService).getPocById(1);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Poc response = target("poc/1").request().get(Poc.class);
        assertEquals(dto.getId(), response.getId());
        assertEquals(dto.getName(), response.getName());
        assertEquals(dto.getDate(), response.getDate());
        assertEquals(dto.getDateTime(), response.getDateTime());

        verify(mockedPocService).getPocById(1);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockedPocService);
    }
}
```

Comment: `mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());` should be enough.

Comment: related to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166217/localdatetime-deserialization-with-localdatetime-parse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You registered the `ContextResolver` with the server via the `configure()` method of the `JerseyTest`, but if you look at the exception, you'll see that is a client side exception (notice the `client` in the package name). So the problem is on the client side. What you are missing is that the deserialization also needs to happen on the client side from JSON to `Poc`, so you also need the `ContextResolver` registered on the client. To do that, you can override `configureClient()` on the `JerseyTest` and register the `ContextResolver` there.

```
@Override
public void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
    config.register(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);
}
```

Comment: I wasted a full day on this, working around countless other things that don't work out of the box when using the Jersey Test Framework. Finally, this was the last missing piece, thanks a lot.