# ObjectMapper configuation for Java 8 Time API

Tags: java, jackson, java-time, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

We're migrating from Joda to Java Time. Currently we use `DateTime` of Joda in our entity. AFAIK `DateTime` is equivalent to two types in Java: `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`. Since we're going to persist them in DB, we're gonna use `OffsetDateTime` (any comment on this?).

Now the problem is how to configure Jackson's `ObjectMapper` properly.
All examples I found on the web are about local types for which Jackson's already provided de/serializer implementations (e.g. `LocalDateTime`, `LocalDateTimeSerializer` and `LocalDateTimeDeserializer`).

I finally managed to do something like this:

```java
public class OffsetDateTimeSerializer extends StdSerializer<OffsetDateTime> {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter; // We need custom format!

    public OffsetDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
        super(OffsetDateTime.class);
        this.formatter = formatter;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(OffsetDateTime value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        generator.writeString(value.format(formatter));
    }

}
```

and

```java
public class OffsetDateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<OffsetDateTime> {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter; // We need custom format!

    public OffsetDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
        super(OffsetDateTime.class);
        this.formatter = formatter;
    }

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(parser.readValueAs(String.class), formatter);
    }

}
```

Now my question is what is the best way to configure Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to de/serialize Java 8 date-time values?

UPDATE: the accepted answer does not really solve my problem (read the discussion in comments). I ended up with a little simpler code than what I proposed in the above. See my own answer as well.

Comment: You don't need to write that yourself, there is already a Jackson module for the Java 8 date and time API: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

Comment: Updated the question. How to use custom format?

Comment: related to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166217/localdatetime-deserialization-with-localdatetime-parse

Comment: I guess so. Our format is `2016-05-11T17:32:20.897+0000` or `2016-05-11T17:32:20.897+00:00` (No Zulu notation) (we want to support multiple formats for inputs)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to write your custom serializer and deserializer for [JSR-310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) types. Jackson has a custom module to handle that and will provide you with the [serializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/OffsetDateTimeSerializer.html) and [deserializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/OffsetTimeDeserializer.html) you need.

First add the `jackson-datatype-jsr310` artifact to your dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Then register the [`JavaTimeModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) module in your [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

Most JSR-310 types will be serialized using a standard ISO-8601 string representation. If you need a custom format, you can use your own serializer and deserializer implementation.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But then how to use custom format?

Comment: @Rad Most JSR-310 types will be serialized using a standard ISO-8601 string representation. If you need a custom format, you can use your own serializer and deserializer implementation.

Comment: So the implementation I posted is the only way to go?

Comment: @Rad Yes. That's the way to go if you want a custom format.

Comment: Beware the microseconds part of ISO-8601. We've had issues with timestamps missing the .SSS part when serializing Instants where it happens to be .000. If that's a problem for your clients, you'll want to customize the serialization to use a custom pattern that doesn't do this: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'".

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin would you please take a look at my own answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018489/2194119.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so I ended up with the following (a little less code, no concrete classes):

```java
private JavaTimeModule newJavaTimeModule() {
    JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
    module.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer(DEFAULT_LOCAL_DATE_FORMATTER));
    module.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer(DEFAULT_LOCAL_DATE_FORMATTER));
    module.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, offsetDateTimeSerializer(DEFAULT_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER));
    module.addDeserializer(OffsetDateTime.class, offsetDateTimeDeserializer(DEFAULT_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER));

    return module;
}

private StdSerializer<OffsetDateTime> offsetDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
    return new OffsetDateTimeSerializer(OffsetDateTimeSerializer.INSTANCE, false, formatter) {};
}

private StdDeserializer<OffsetDateTime> offsetDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
    return new InstantDeserializer<OffsetDateTime>(InstantDeserializer.OFFSET_DATE_TIME, formatter) {};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this answer, that contains a lot of information about how to use java.time classes and custom formats: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46263957

To parse both "+00:00" and "+0000", you can use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` with optional sections:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date and time fields
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    // optional offset in format hh:mm
    .optionalStart()
    .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "+00:00")
    .optionalEnd()
    // optional offset in format hhmm
    .optionalStart()
    .appendOffset("+HHMM", "+0000")
    .optionalEnd()
    .toFormatter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot does dependency management for Jackson. Upon 2.6, the jsr310 module can be managed automatically, so you just use Jackson 2.6+ and the module is added, which is available in `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310`.

If you have access to the `ObjectMapper`, such as in a unit test, you can register the `JavaTimeModule` . If you don't, like what happens when the JSON comes in as `@RequestBody`, you must configure in application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```

And specify the date format in JSON like:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXX")
private OffsetDateTime transactionDateTime;
```

And the string will be parsed correctly. The format uses the letters specified in `SimpleDateFormat`.

Mind the number of `X` at the end; varied length of which represents distinct forms of zone offset. Read Java API `SimpleDateFormat` part for more information.